# Display time remaining in zenity progress bar

Tags: zenity

Is it possible for the zenity progress bar to display time remaining or transfer per second (MB/s) for the progress ? For example, by using

***dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null status=progress***

The command above will result in :
[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDLZD.png)

So, if possible I want the progress bar to have all the information from the log. If it’s not possible, how can I make it so when the cloning process run, it will show the status=progress log and zenity progress bar at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know a proper answer on your question, but i have solved a similar problem, so i'll post it  here and  maybe someone will find it useful.
To show a progress of archiving files i have used this command:

```
(pv -n $root_path/save/$backup_save_src_file |pigz -c > $backup_path/save/${backup_save_src_file%%.*}$backup_date.gz) 2>&1 | zenity --progress --percentage=0 --title="Backupping" --text="Cloning file into archive..." --auto-close
```

- **pv -n $root_path/save/$backup_save_src_file** - will read file and output raw progress value separated by new line on standart error *(man pv for more options)*
- **pigz -c > $backup_path/save/${backup_save_src_file%%.*}$backup_date.gz** - piped contents are directed into  archiver for compressing
- **(...) 2>&1 | zenity ...** - redirect STDERR to STDOUT and finally pipe it to zenity